# Using LinkedIn API to search and display a member's profile using keyword search

Tags: php, json, api, search, linkedin-api

I would like to use the LinkedIn API to display the publicly available information of a person, after passing it keywords as a search term

I can get my code to display various profile info using a search URL such as:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,headline),num-results)?first-name=FOO&last-name=BAR
```

However when I change this to:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,headline),num-results)?keywords=FOO%20BAR
```

I get 0 results

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Both seem to be working on the test console; here are the results from your first query:

https://snap.apigee.com/TCWiFS

And for the second query:

https://snap.apigee.com/UtGAm6

What name are you searching for?

Comment: Here is my first-name%last-name search
https://snap.apigee.com/RuH8nn

Here is my keyword search returning 0 results:
https://snap.apigee.com/SfFXKo

Comment: Strange. I would post something to the [LinkedIn Developer's Site](http://developer.linkedin.com/) in the [REST forums](https://developer.linkedin.com/forums/rest) and report this, as it may be a bug.